# Query that returns records on total sum of quantity less or equal to some value

Tags: sql-server-2008, common-table-expression

```
DECLARE @TotalMaxQty int
SET @TotalMaxQty = 1000

SELECT
  PKId
  ,Qty
FROM dbo.Sales

PKId          Qty
____          _____
1             100
2             200 
3             750
4             200
...
```

I have to get 1, 2, 3 records because of `SUM(Qty) <= @TotalMaxQty` (record 3 should be included partially with Qty = 700).

Thank you.

Comment: This is basically running totals. How many rows typically will your query be returning? That will determine whether a triangular join approach is feasible.

Comment: @Martin Smith no more 500-800 records per query.

Comment: Ah right. Shouldn't be too bad with a triangular join then (self join on `Sales1.PKId < Sales2.PKId`)

Comment: @Martin Smith good direction! I will do something in this way...

Comment: 100 + 200 + 750 is 1050, and therefore > 1000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE to calculate the running sum.

```
declare @Sales table (PKId int, Qty int)

insert into @Sales values
(1,             100),
(2,             200), 
(3,             750),
(4,             200)

declare @TotalMaxQty int = 1000

;with OrderedSales as
(
  select PKId,
         Qty,
         row_number() over(order by PKId) as rn
  from @Sales
  --where "some where clause against Sales"
),
RunningSum as
(
  select OS.PKId,
         case when OS.Qty < @TotalMaxQty then OS.Qty
              else @TotalMaxQty
         end as Qty,
         @TotalMaxQty - OS.Qty as Rest,
         OS.rn
  from OrderedSales OS
  where rn = 1
  union all
  select OS.PKId,
         case when OS.Qty < RS.Rest then OS.Qty
              else RS.Rest
         end as Qty,
         RS.Rest - OS.Qty,
         OS.rn
  from OrderedSales as OS
    inner join RunningSum as RS
      on OS.rn = RS.rn + 1
  where RS.Rest > 0
)
select PKId,
       Qty
from RunningSum
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

**Edit:** A version that stores the ordered sales in a table variable with `rn` as a primary key. My tests shows much improved performance.

```
declare @Sales table (PKId int, Qty int)

insert into @Sales values
(1,             100),
(2,             200), 
(3,             750),
(4,             200)

declare @TotalMaxQty int = 1000

declare @OrderedSales table
( 
  rn int primary key,
  PKId int,
  Qty int
)

insert into @OrderedSales
select row_number() over(order by PKId),
       PKId,
       Qty
from @Sales
--where "some where clause against Sales"

;with RunningSum as
(
  select OS.PKId,
         case when OS.Qty < @TotalMaxQty then OS.Qty
              else @TotalMaxQty
         end as Qty,
         @TotalMaxQty - OS.Qty as Rest,
         OS.rn
  from @OrderedSales OS
  where rn = 1
  union all
  select OS.PKId,
         case when OS.Qty < RS.Rest then OS.Qty
              else RS.Rest
         end as Qty,
         RS.Rest - OS.Qty,
         OS.rn
  from @OrderedSales as OS
    inner join RunningSum as RS
      on OS.rn = RS.rn + 1
  where RS.Rest > 0

)
select PKId,
       Qty
from RunningSum
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Comment: @garik - It is the first CTE that is the cuplrit, or rather the lack of index on column `rn`. Added a version where the result ordered sales result is stored in a table variable that is then used recursively. If that is doable for you there will be much better performance.

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines should do the trick. (NB: The reason for having the `TOP` and the subquery is to stop the triangular join calculations as soon as the target is reached)

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Sales
WHERE   PKId < = ( SELECT TOP 1
                            S1.PKId
                   FROM     Sales S1
                            LEFT JOIN Sales S2 ON S1.PKId >= S2.PKId
                   GROUP BY S1.PKId
                   HAVING   SUM(S2.Qty) >= @TotalMaxQty
                   ORDER BY PKId
                 )
```

Answer (score 1):

> record 3 should be included partially with Qty = 700

That part is a bad idea to do in sql, for two reason: it's just more efficient to do it in client code, and to do this right you'll also want to also update or insert a record somewhere to know how much of that quantity is remaining (meaning you need another difficult query).

But if you insist:

```
SELECT s.PKId, CASE WHEN PriorTotal + Qty > @TotalMaxQty THEN @TotalMaxQty - PriorTotal ELSE Qty END As Qty
FROM SALES s
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT s1.PKId, Sum(s2.Qty) As PriorTotal 
   FROM SALES s1
   LEFT JOIN SALES s2 ON s2.PKId < s1.PKId
   GROUP BY s1.PKId
) q ON q.PKId = s.PKId
WHERE q.PriorTotal < @TotalMaxQty
ORDER BY s.Qty
```

Comment: @garik - fixed it. Was matching on qty rather than pkid on the inner-most join, and added an order by for fun.

Comment: nice! thanks for you make me thinking about it, one fix you forget (for fun of course) about `Sum(ISNULL(s2.Qty, s1.Qty)) As PriorTotal` :) the first records was shifted